# How to remove rows which have equal values in all columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with ~4000 rows with gene expression.

```
DF<-read.table("Sample_DF.txt",header=T)
head(DF, 4)


# Gene_Symbol     X.U1.     X.T1.     X.U2.     X.T2.
# 1        M1AP 0.0440509 0.1164950 0.0574035 0.0000000
# 2        DRD4 0.0440114 0.0387834 0.0512446 0.0497801
# 3        PCA3 0.0439278 0.0258183 0.0000000 0.0329761
# 4     FAM153B 0.0439073 0.0409539 0.0658340 0.3767400

tail(DF, 4)

#      Gene_Symbol X.U1. X.T1. X.U2. X.T2.
# 3992   LINC00353     0     0     0     0
# 3993   LINC00359     0     0     0     0
# 3994   LINC00366     0     0     0     0
# 3995   LINC00379     0     0     0     0
```

Now, I want to remove all the rows which contains 0 in all columns. 
I have searched through all similar queries here and in other websites and used the code:

```
DF_filtered <- DF[!apply(DF[,c(2:5)],1,function(z) all(z==0)),]
```

or

```
DF_filtered <- DF[apply(DF[,c(2:5)],1,function(z) all(z!=0)),]
```

or

```
DF_filtered <- DF[apply(DF[,c(2:5)],1,function(z) any(z!=0)),].
```

However, nothing worked and no line is being deleted from the original dataset. Could someone please help me sort this out.

Comment: try setting this up in your read in `read.table(na.strings = "0")`. It will take all the 0's in your data frame and convert them to NAs, then you can use `na.omit(DF)`

Comment: for future reference tho you should really post a `dput(sample_DF)` so that everyone that helps could make sure solutions work with your specific case in question

Comment: I'm with @NathanDay on that matter, but if you already stuck with a loaded data, I would go with ```df[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[-1], `==`, 0)),]```

Comment: @NathanDay : I want to remove rows were all columns values are 0. I dont want to remove all zeroes. Is there a way I can upload my sample dataset here? I think that might help. Thanks

Comment: Sure just run `dput(your_df)` and edit your question with a paste of that output. It allows me to then run that paste and get the exact same data you are looking at including pesky attributes like class.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have negative values in your columns you can filter your dataframe based on the row indexes that meet the condition of `rowSums` being equal to 0.

Assuming your data is called `df`:

`df <- df[-which(rowSums(df[2:5])==0), ]`

**Edit** - including safer way of filtering suggested by @akrun based on vector of TRUE/FALSE rather than a vector of indexes that could potentially be empty:

`df <- df[!rowSums(df[2:5])==0, ]`

Comment: As you suggested: I tried this option        DF_filtered<- DF[-which(rowSums(DF[2:5])==0), ] but getting an error Error in rowSums(DF[2:5]) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Are those 4 columns numeric? you can check with `str(DF)`. `rowSums` doesn't work with character or factor columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my original data 2nd column was chromosomal position, thats the reason my original code didnot work. Thanks for pointing it out. I could successfully filter my data.

Comment: It is better to use a logical vector instead of numeric and then using `-` as it can get into trouble for egde cases.  Plus one.

Comment: Suppose if there are no cases where `==0`, then it could be a problem.  For example `v1 <- 1:5; v1[-which(v1 == 0)]#
integer(0)`